# Methods to notify an external symfony2 app of an event

Tags: php, symfony, events

I have two Symfony2 apps running on different servers. I need a mechanism to notify one app of an event in the second app. I am somehow not happy with the approaches known to me which are:

1. Signed request

   I can call a secure controller action from my second app on the event. But the drawback of this solution is that the event gets lost if the other app is down. I want the app to be able to process the events whenever it comes up after a downtime.
2. Worker queue

   Using Amazon's SQS queue would work fine for my requirement. But workers are known to hog memory.

I want to achieve the best possible implementation for this. I'm not known to many patterns of service interactions. Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of alternatives to Amazon SQS - http://queues.io/

**RabbitMQ** is good one. If your messages are small and you have private network you can use **Beanstalkd** - it's very fast and simple.

There are bundles for Symfony you can use

- https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle
- https://github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any other interaction mechanisms for service interactions?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [message bus](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageBus.html). You can easily make your talk to each other with [enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) library. I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.forma-pro.com/message-bus-to-every-php-application-42a7d3fbb30b) about Symfony <-> Magento integration via the message bus.

Let's say you have application Foo and Bar. You have to install enqueue and a transport (that [suppports message bus](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/client/supported_brokers.md)). RabbitMQ supports it so I am choosing amqp transport.

Installation:

```
composer require enqueue/enqueue-bundle enqueue/amqp-ext
```

Configuration:

```
# app/config/config.php

enqueue:
  transport:
    default: 'amqp://'
  client:
    app_name: 'foo' # for the foo app
    app_name: 'bar' # for the bar app
```

Now you can [send event messages](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/bundle/message_producer.md#client) and [register processors](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/bundle/message_processor.md) subscribing them to the topics. Whenever you send a message to the topic (does not matter what app) it will be delivered to all apps interested in it.